# Hercules Inpulse 200 MIDI DJ controller not detected in Mixxx on Arch Linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, modprobe, dj

My Hercules Inpulse 200 MIDI DJ controller is not detected in Mixxx on Arch Linux, even though the soundcard is found in PulseAudio.

Some forums suggest `sudo modprobe -a snd_seq_midi` which however results in `modprobe: WARNING: Module snd_seq_midi not found in directory /lib/modules...`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried turning it off and on again...?

**Rebooting with the controller attached** via USB finally did the trick and Mixxx now detects the controller.

The mappings for Hercules Inpulse 300 are working fine for Inpulse 200 as well so far.